# JSON-DATA: Display input in the com_ back-end and save data in the DB

Tags: component, development, joomla-api, jform

I'm developing my custom component for storing some records in the DB. In my **#__records** DB table there is the column **attribs** where I want to store some data in json-format like:

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}
```

I try to add the input for the **field1** in my **admin/models/forms/record.xml** like:

```
<fields name="attribs">
  <fieldset name="basic">
     <field name="field1" type="text" />
  </fieldset>
</fields>
```

and I can render it in my **admin/views/record/tmpl/default.php** via foreach:

```
<?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
    <?php echo $field->input; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Although at that the **field1** hasn't its value that is already stored in the DB.

**There are two questions:**

**1.** How can I render the input in **views/record/tmpl/default.php** not via foreach but like:

```
echo $this->form->getInput('field1'); // it doesn't display the input at all
```

and with its stored value

**2.** How can I save new value of the **field1** i.e. what code should I add to the **save($data)** function in my **admin/models/record.php** (or to JTable class)? I need something like:

```
public function save($data)
{
   if(isset($data['attribs']) && isset($data['attribs']['field1']))
   {
      // what code should be here ???
   }
   return parent::save($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, yet I resolved the first issue with the code:

```
$json = $this->item->attribs;
$obj = json_decode($json);
$value1 = $obj->{"field1"};
echo $this->form->getField('field1','attribs')->label;
echo '<input type="text" name="jform[attribs][field1]" id="jform_attribs_field1" value="'.$value1.'" class="inputbox" size="40" />';
```

and to the save($data) function in the model I've added only the code:

```
$attribs = array();
$attribs['field1'] = $data['attribs']['field1'];
$data['attribs'] = json_encode($attribs);
```

There is no need to add something to getForm method

Now everything works perfectly but any better solution would be appreciated

Comment: getForm method is optional to override. Glad you solved this issue! Accept your answer whenever you are allowed to :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please see following answers to your question:

> You can render individual field as follows:

```
echo $this->form->getField('field1')->label;
echo $this->form->getField('field1')->input;
```

At this time you would not have a value to above input field. If you want to give default value to your field1 then you can do following in your model:

Make sure that you are extending your model with JModelForm or JModelAdmin

override getForm method

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
        $form = $this->loadForm('com_yourcomponent.formname', 'formname', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

  if (empty($form))
  {
      return false;
  }            

  $form->setFieldAttribute('field1', 'default', 'Your Value');

  return $form;
}
```

If you want to get value in runtime them do following:

In your save($data) method of Model

```
public function save($data)
{
   // Get the value of field1 with it's name. Make sure to check if value exists.
   $field1 = $data['field1'];
   $field2 = $data['field2'];

   // Merge both field's value to one Array
   $attribs = array('field1' => $field1, 'field2' => $field2);

   // Convert it to JSON object
   $data['attribs'] = json_encode($attribs);
   return parent::save($data);
}
```

Comment: If I use `echo $this->form->getField('field1')->input;` I get the error: **Trying to get property of non-object in ...** and any value is not being saved in the DB with your code for the model

Comment: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JForm.html Look at this API it says getField method is correct. Looks like your form is not loading that field. Try to debug your code by doing print_r($this->form) and see if you can get your field there.

Comment: Oh, you missed $group string — there should be: `echo $this->form->getField('field1','attribs')->input;` Now I get the field. However it still hasn't its value that is already stored in the DB and has default value from XML-form